# looking for way to delete fragments from not existing data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have following tables

```
report_pre    { id, date}
report_sections   {id,report,data}
```

I want to delete table fragments with following sql code:-

```
DELETE
FROM
report_sections
WHERE
report=ANY(
    SELECT 
        rs.report 
    FROM 
        report_sections rs 
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                rp.id
            FROM
                report_pre rp
            WHERE
                rp.id=rs.report
        )
)
```

But I get the message:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'report_sections' for update in FROM clause

What am I doing wrong?
I tried it already different ways, but found no solution so far.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do what you want:

```
DELETE rs
    FROM report_sections rs LEFT JOIN
         report_pre rp
         on rp.id = rs.report
    WHERE rp.id IS NULL;
```

This will delete all rows from `report_sections` that don't have a matching record in `report_pre`.

I think the error message is pretty clear on your original message.  You can work around it by using an additional layer of subqueries.  But, it is fun to learn the `join` method to get around this problem.